# Cannot get my .htaccess regular expression to work as intended

Tags: regex, .htaccess

I use my .htaccess for pretty urls using regex.

I have multiple `RewriteRule` rules in my .htaccess and they all work great.

I am having a problem with one of them which i cannot workout where i am going wrong, it just brings me to my 404 page not found.

```
RewriteRule ^member/password-reset/v/([0-9]+)?/([0-9]+)?/([a-z0-9]+)?$ /member/password-reset-verify.php?&uid=$1&id=$1&t=$1 [NC,L]
```

The ugly url looks like this (without the parentheses):

**/member/password-reset-verify.php?&uid=(user_uid_here)&id=(another_id_here)&t=(token)**

I would like the pretty url to look like this (without parentheses)

**/member/password-reset/v/(user_uid_here)/(another_id_here)/(token)**

- uid (contains only numbers)
- id (contains only numbers)
- token (can contain letters and numbers)

Unfortunately i cannot get the `RewriteRule` to work. I would appreciate any help in getting it to work.

Comment: And what _exactly_ does "cannot get it to work" actually mean? Although there are a few details that can be optimized the rule you posted should work for what you ask. So the question is what prevents it from getting applied. Most likely this is a question of context, but you did not provide much of a context to us. So please post your full set of rewriting rules, add what you see in your http servers error log file and the _exact_ URL requested along with the _exact_ error message you receive back. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I already mentioned some issues with this question in my comment above.

Nevertheless I will post an attempt to clean up your current rule a bit:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/?member/password-reset/v/(\d+)/(\d+)?/(\w+)/?$ /member/password-reset-verify.php?uid=$1&id=$2&t=$3 [END]
```

In case you receive back an http status 500 (internal server error) chances are that you operate a very old version of the apache http server. You will see a definite hint to an undefined `END` flag in your http server's error log file. In that case try using the old `L` flag instead, it will *probably* work the same, though this depends a bit on your setup.

This rule will work likewise in the http server's host configuration or in a dynamic configuration file (".htaccess"). If you have access to the http server's host configuration then you should not use dynamic configuration files at all, they come with a ton of disadvantages. They are only offered for people stuck with a really cheap hosting provider as a last option for fine tuning.

Comment: for some reason this works fine, even though i thought the one i provided should to (although poorly written), my .htaccess file is rather dated and has not been touched in a long time so need to get it sorted, i am running ampps latest version 3.8 (apache 2.4.27, MySQL 5.6.37, PHP 7.1.8) running locally on my laptop development machine, site is not live or anything i enjoy programming as a hobby and just got back into it after 7 years so rather allot of changes since then. sorry for the late reply to. many thanks.

Comment: Sounds great, welcome back to programming and great I could help. Have fun!